# How can I SELECT multiple columns based on rows returned?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I run a SELECT query and it returns rows that have redundant information in them, how can I present that information in one row?

Currently my query is like this:

```
SELECT email, first_name, group FROM membership
```

And that returns a result set like so:

```
------------------------------------
|    email    | first_name | group |
------------------------------------
|  bob@co.uk  |     bob    |   g1  |
|  jim@co.uk  |     jim    |   g1  |
|  jim@co.uk  |     jim    |   g2  |
|  jane@co.uk |    henry   |   g2  |
------------------------------------
```

Instead, I need the result set to look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
|    email    | first_name | group | group |
--------------------------------------------
|  bob@co.uk  |     bob    |   g1  |       |
|  jim@co.uk  |     jim    |   g1  |   g2  |
|  jane@co.uk |    henry   |   g2  |       |
--------------------------------------------
```

It's important that the column name "group" is not named differently despite being redundant.

edit: for clarity, the number of groups may change.
edit2: The full code I'm using, for the initial query, is:

```
SELECT 
    persons.mail AS email,
    persons.fname AS 'first_name',
persons.lname AS 'last_name',
groups.name as add_list
FROM group_membership
LEFT JOIN groups ON group_membership.gid = groups.gid
LEFT JOIN persons ON group_membership.uid = persons.uid
WHERE persons.mail != ""
ORDER BY last_name
```

Comment: Can we see your *actual* query?

Comment: what about using `group email, first_name` and aggregate groups by `group_concat` ?   `select email, first_name, group_concat(group) from membership group by email, first_name`

Comment: it is theoretically possible to distribute groups like you wish, but you need to know the full range of possible group values. even in that case, suppose there is just a few members with maximum number of groups (say 100), it doesn't make sense to put 100 columns into the schema because of those few members

Comment: @mangusta, you're right. I'm rethinking this in light of your comment and ronald-aaronson's answer. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible. If there were four rows with the value:

```
|  jim@co.uk  |     jim    |   g2  |
```

would you expect the result to have 4 columns named `group` instead of the two columns of `group` that you currently show?

What you probably want is:

```
select email, first_name, group_concat(`group`) group by email, first_name
```

Comment: Yes, my hope is that the quantity of columns would increase as more results match the email address.

Comment: @DonnieG Unfortunately, relational databases do not work that way; the number of columns is predetermined by your select statement. But `group_concat` will place in *one* column more and more data as more data matches the email address/first_name combination.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data this will do:

```
select email, first_name,
  min(`group`) `group`, 
  case when max(`group`) <> min(`group`) then max(`group`) end `group`
from membership
group by email, first_name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f47b27671b1a77fe56ef1826128d99b8).
Results:

```
> email      | first_name | group | group
> :--------- | :--------- | :---- | :----
> bob@co.uk  | bob        | g1    | 
> jane@co.uk | henry      | g2    | 
> jim@co.uk  | jim        | g1    | g2
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately only works for two groups. Once there are more than two groups, more columns will not be created to make room.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above sample the below would work

```
     SELECT email, first_name, max(case 
        when 
      group ='g1' then group else null end) 
       as groupg1, 
      max(case 
        when 
      group ='g2' then group else null end) 
       as groupg2
      FROM membership group by email, 
      first_name
```

Comment: he didn't say that there are two groups only

Comment: Neither he said there are more

Comment: so what, that doesn't mean the solution should handle that specific case only